# Wire Identification

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

This is a three-gang switch in a home I just bought. I am not an electrician by any means, so this is probably going to be a question for curiosity sake.

Is it possible to tell me which wire is what from this picture? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering where in the world you are that some sort of wiring splice that appears to be nothing but some electrical tape meets the modern wiring code.

Comment: That's not a splice, it's grouping the travelers, as longneck notes. The green hot weirds **me** out, but I'm aware that some parts of the world do that.

Answer (score 2):

- The red wire is the "hot" and supplies power to the switches.
- The black wire and the green wire with the white paint are the switched hots. Those run to the light or outlets that the switches control.
- The two green wires that are taped together are traveler wires for a 3-way switch arrangement.

Comment: Looks more like the **red is the hot** - that's the one that's connected to the other two switches by the black jumpers.

Comment: Oops, you're right.

Comment: Well, it would certainly be clearer if they had used red jumper wire.